# Removing non-break-spaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble removing spaces from a string. First I am converting the *div* to `text();` to remove the tags (which works) and then I'm trying to remove the "`&nbsp`" part of the string, but it won't work. Any Idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
newStr = $('#myDiv').text();
newStr = newStr.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');

$('#myText').val(newStr);


<html>
  <div id = "myDiv"><p>remove&nbsp;space</p></div>
  <input type = "text" id = "myText" />
</html>
```

Comment: `&nbsp;` won't be interpreted as a HTML entity in your JS file.

Comment: `&nbsp;` is an HTML entity - in the `.text()`'s return it is the same as white space.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I don't think so. &nbsp; will be converted to a real [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Comment: @ComFreek You're right, I expressed myself badly. It won't be converted to U+0020 as my comment indicates but rather U+00A0.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you use the `text` function, you're not getting HTML, but text: the `&nbsp;` entities have been changed to spaces.

#### So simply replace spaces:

```js
var str = " a     b   ", // bunch of NBSPs 
    newStr = str.replace(/\s/g,'');
    
console.log(newStr)
```

If you want to replace only the spaces coming from `&nbsp;` do the replacement before the conversion to text:

```
newStr = $($('#myDiv').html().replace(/&nbsp;/g,'')).text();
```

Comment: This also replaces all other kinds of whitespace!

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't even know you could nest selectors in jquery. Thank you very much. Great answer

Answer (score 23):

`.text()`/`textContent` do not contain HTML entities (such as `&nbsp;`), these are returned as literal characters. Here's a regular expression using the [non-breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) Unicode escape sequence:

```
var newStr = $('#myDiv').text().replace(/\u00A0/g, '');
$('#myText').val(newStr);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/EPOHohe/2/edit)

It is also possible to use a literal non-breaking space character instead of the escape sequence in the Regex, however I find the escape sequence more clear in this case. Nothing that a comment wouldn't solve, though.

It is also possible to use `.html()`/`innerHTML` to retrieve the HTML containing HTML entities, as in @Dystroy's answer.

---

*Below is my original answer, where I've misinterpreted OP's use case. I'll leave it here in case anyone needs to remove `&nbsp;` from DOM elements' text content*

[...] However, be aware that re-setting the `.html()`/`innerHTML` of an element means trashing out all of the listeners and data associated with it.

So here's a recursive solution that only alters the text content of text nodes, without reparsing HTML nor any side effects.

```
function removeNbsp($el) {
  $el.contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
      this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/\u00A0/g, '');
    } else {
      removeNbsp( $(this) );
    }
  });
}
removeNbsp( $('#myDiv') );
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/EPOHohe/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks for the demo, I'll check it out now.

Comment: The purpose doesn't seem to be to reset the HTML, as it is set as value of an input.

Comment: @dystroy Oh yes, I was wondering what was the purpose of the `input` tag there until now that I saw the `.val()` call. I'll tidy up this answer a bit then.

Comment: The regex is actually more specific than simple spaces.