# Get start position of substring in string with &nbsp; and HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I'm having a challenge getting an accurate starting position in a string with mixed content (HTML and text). The content is entered by users into a contenteditable div.  I can't use textareas because HTML tags can be added to the content and textareas don't accept anything but text.

In the app, users enter text and then they are given the opportunity to select text for highlighting (the app adds `<span class="hilite"></span>` tags to the selected text) and "tags" (`<span>{{selected text}}<sup>{{tagname}}</sup></span>` tags) so that a string can look like this:

```
a very&nbsp; <span class="hilite">unhappy</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; person <span>made life very difficult<sup>problem</sup></span> for another person
```

The `&nbsp;` items appear to be added by the browser (a unique feature of contenteditable divs?) any time there is more than one space sequentially and this can appear as "  `&nbsp;`" (regular space first) or "`&nbsp;` " (regular space last) or a series of `&nbsp;` spaces with a regular space at the beginning or the end.

Because this is user driven input, it's never known how many  tags or `&nbsp;` spaces will be found in a string. Either way, the goal is to count every character in the *literal* html string up to the beginning of the selected text.

For example, if the user wants to "tag" the second instance of "person", the user highlights the word, then a right click will pop up a modal with the selected text. At the moment of the right click, I need to get an accurate position of the selected text in the context of the whole string as it exists at the time. And, of course, I won't know how many spans, sups or `&nbsp;` elements there are or how many instances of "person" there might be.

Here's my basic event handler for the right click (using jQuery):

```
$('.editableDiv').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let fullString = $(this).html();
    let selectedText = window.getSelection();
    let textStart = {{what goes here is the problem}}
    $.ajax(
         {{send arguments to server, 
             do stuff, 
             return the amended string 
             replace the contents of the $(this) with the returned string}}
    );
});
```

The specific problem is how do I set the value of textStart accurately.

JavaScript's `string.indexOf(person)` won't work because it only finds the first instance of person and I'll never know how many instances there will be since the user is entering the text and selecting the text to manipulate.

I've also tried traversing the DOM like this (called with selectedText from above as `selection`):

```
function findTheStartPosition(selection) {
    let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    let startContainer = range.startContainer;
    let start = 0;
    for (let node of Array.from(startContainer.parentElement.childNodes)) {
        if (node === startContainer) {
            break;
        }
        if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            start += node.textContent.length;
        } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            let tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
            tempDiv.appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
            start += tempDiv.innerHTML.length;
        }
    }
    start += range.startOffset;

    return start;
}
```

And that works well, except when there are `&nbsp;` elements because `range.startOffset` counts all `&nbsp;` characters as single space and thus the position is inaccurate.

I'm trying to avoid stripping the main string of all tags and spaces because it will require keeping track of what was stripped and the length of each item stripped (including a count of 6 characters for every `&nbsp;`) and then having to rebuild the string to preserve the tags (but not the superfluous spaces)....nightmare.

All I need is a simple, reliable way to get the start position of the user selected text in a string.

**Update 1**

For clarity, lets call the original string (as shown above) the "dirty string" and the user-selected substring the "selectedText".
The acceptable solution could be either:

A) A function that properly returns the exact starting point of the selectedText in the dirty string; OR

B) A function that returns a "clean string" (`&nbsp;`s converted into single spaces) and the exact starting point of the selectedText in the "clean string".

Bear in mind that:

- there can be duplicate text in the dirty string. Simple "search-for-phrase" options will not work
- there can be any number of `&nbsp;`s present in the string and they need to be counted as 6 characters in the "dirty string"
- any conversion of `&nbsp;`s to
  single spaces has to account for the loss of 5 characters per
  conversion *prior to the start* of the selectedText

Comment: A very simple approach would be to replace all `&nbsp;` occurences with a placeholdervalue like `_` for counting purpose.

Comment: @Slevin - sounds simple enough; care to share some code to do this?

Comment: `findTheStartPosition(selection.replace(/&nbsp;/g, "______")) {`

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether you mean one `&nbsp;` gets counted as one char or multiple occurences (HTML displays multiple whitespaces as once), however, you might just tinker with a temporary replacement solution for counting purposes only. So depending on your result, replace with one or multiple placeholder values.

Comment: I won't know how many occurrences of `&nbsp;` are present in the string and/or whether `&nbsp;` will be preceeded by or followed by a regular space.  To get an accurate position of the selectedText I only need to convert and count the `&nbsp;` before the selectedText. But I can't use indexOf for the position of the selectedText in the case where the selectedText might appear in multiple places.

Comment: So the `&nbsp;`s are added by the browser and you don't like that? I don't understand, why don't you just replace them with regular spaces? It's very easy to implement with JS.

Comment: @SNBS - unfortunately at the moment that the user chooses a selection of the text they've entered and right clicks (the `contextmenu` event in js). I need the exact position of the highlighted text before I go replace the `&nbsp;`s with a single space.  I could preprocess the string and replace the `&nbsp;s` with single spaces, but to do the math to re-calculate the beginning of the user-selected string after replacement, I only need to do that for the `&nbsp;`s that precede the user selection. Now we're full-circle, where do I stop counting the replaced `&nbsp;`s?

Comment: I think you can just replace all the `&nbsp;`s, since they all mean a regular space — why not

Comment: Because window.getSelection() counts `&nbsp;` as six spaces and a regular space as 1

Comment: Then you could traverse through the nodes before selection and replace `&nbsp;`s there prior to computing the length. As well as in the `startContainer` in the text content from start to `startOffset`.

Comment: Possibly.  This is all happening in real time.  So traversing through the nodes as input is being entered and not knowing when or where in the string the user is going to select a string sounds like a risky proposition.  Or am I missing something?  Also I can't rely on startContainer offsets because the "start" is only relative to the previous tag.  In the example text shown in my post, the literal start position of the first "person" is 62.  `startOffset` will show it as 13 (two `&nbsp;`s at 6 characters each plus a regular space, as counted from the end of the span tag that precedes it.

Comment: You didn't get it. See my answer.

Comment: @globalSchmidt  do you want like this? https://jsfiddle.net/4ckb7pwo/

Comment: @Anant - the fiddle doesn't work; if you look at the fiddle console.log it throws `NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED ERROR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my riff on @Heiko's solution:

```
function extract(div) {
    let contents = div[0].innerHTML;
    let r = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    let newParent = document.createElement("_");
    r.surroundContents(newParent);
    let start = div[0].innerHTML.indexOf("<_>");
    let end = div[0].innerHTML.indexOf("</_>") - 3;
    let beginString = div[0].innerHTML.substring(0,start).replace(/(&amp;nbsp;|&nbsp;)/g, '');
    let selectedText =  div[0].innerHTML.substring((start + 3), (end+3));
    let newText = wrapInNewTags(selectedText);
    let endString = div[0].innerHTML.substring(end+7).replace(/(&amp;nbsp;|&nbsp;)/g, '');
    let reassembledString = beginString + newText + endString;
    console.log('reassembledString', reassembledString);
}
```

And a simple function to wrap the solution in new tags:

```
function wrapInNewTags(selection) {
    return '&lt;span class="tagged"&gt;'+selection+'&lt;/span&gt;'.replace(/(&amp;nbsp;|&nbsp;)/g, '');
}
```

Then in PHP, if needed, the `reassembledString` is converted neatly into readable, tagged strings with `htmlspecialchars_decode`;

The minor differences between this and Heiko's solution are:

1. the use of `div[0].innerHTML` vs `div.innerHTML`
2. the cleaning of both `&amp;nbsp;` and `&nbsp;` entities from the string when the desired string is being created from innerHTML content
3. The extraction of the `beginString` and `endString` values as well.

Along the way, I learned that if there is a single `&nbsp;` or html tag with a `<span></span>` in the `contents`, the string that is output from `div[0].innerHTML` converts these to `&amp;nbsp;` or `&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;`, respectively. It's quite ugly when there are multiple tags, but it works.  If you don't follow this format in the `wrapInNewTags` function, you then get some text with readable tags and some items that are htmlentities (using the `&`).

In the end the solution is clean and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a more complex traversing.

```js
document.getElementById("log").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  console.log("Selected " + selection.toString() + " at position " + getStartOf(selection));
});


function nodeTillStartContainer(node, start) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
  let result = div.innerHTML.substring(0, div.innerHTML.indexOf(">") + 1);

  for (let child of Array.from(node.childNodes)) {
    if (child === start) break;
    if (child.contains(start)) {
      result += nodeTillStartContainer(child, start);
      break;
    }
    
    const temp = document.createElement("div");
    temp.appendChild(child.cloneNode(true));
    result += temp.innerHTML;
  }
  
  return result;
}

function handleNbspsBefore(selection) {
  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  const start = range.startContainer;
  let result = "";
  
  let initialContainer = start.parentElement;
  while (!initialContainer.hasAttribute("contentEditable")) {
    initialContainer = initialContainer.parentElement;
  }

  for (let node of Array.from(initialContainer.childNodes)) 
  {
    if (node === start) break;
    if (node.contains(start)) {
      result += nodeTillStartContainer(node, start).replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
      break;
    }

    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      result += node.textContent.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
    } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      const temp = document.createElement("div");
      temp.appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
      result += temp.innerHTML.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
    }
  }

  result += start.textContent.substring(0, range.startOffset).replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");

  return result;
}

function getStartOf(selection) {
  return handleNbspsBefore(selection).length;
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable>a very&nbsp; <span class="highlight">unhappy</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; person <span>made life very difficult<sup>problem</sup></span> for another person</div>
<br/>
<button id="log">Log</button>
```

You no longer need that algorithm from your question, since the traversal is performed in function `handleNbspsBefore`.

*UPDATE:* you want to reassemble the entire string after all. I'll provide an example to make sure you understood me correctly.

```js
const selection = window.getSelection();
const cleanString = dirtyString.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ");
const reassembledCleanString = handleNbspsBefore(selection)
  + wrapInNewTags(selection.toString())
  + cleanString.substring(getStartOf(selection) + selection.toString().length);
```

Comment: After testing your solution, it doesn't give an accurate start position in the string. Using the string in my post, if you were to select "unhappy" in that string, the literal starting point is 35, but your function returns 30, which I suspect is the difference between 6 characters for the first &nbsp; and 1 character for a space. Oddly, selecting the last "person" in the original string (literal position 137) returns 134 despite there being numerous `&nbsp;`s before that.

Comment: I created a fiddle that implements your code. It demonstrates that the numbers returned are different from the actual start point.  (I'm using Notepad++ to determine the character position of the literal string.) Here's the fiddle: jsfiddle.net/7vxc84zn  Paste the test string in the contenteditable div, then highlight a bit of the string and right click to see the position returned by your code.

Comment: Correction to my first comment: the position returned for the last 'person' is 131 vs the actual literal position of 137

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I published code without testing. I made a bit of debugging and the implementation doubled, see my edit :)

Comment: The actual position of last "person" is 124 not 137. You wanted `&nbsp;`s to be treated as a single character, didn't you?

Comment: Sorry this is so hard to communicate.  I need to know the exact position of the beginning of the string that the user has highlighted _as it exists at the time they highlighted it and right clicked_.  Call this the "dirty" string. Sometimes, not always there will be `&nbsp;`s inserted by the browser when the user puts two spaces between words. Once I know precisely where the user-selected string starts in the dirty string I can manipulate/clean the string all day long.  But if I don't know the starting position in the dirty string, I'm toast... I think.

Comment: The short answer to your question is "no".  I initially want to count the string literally, including `&nbsp;`s as six characters.

Comment: With the change in the span tag to "highlight" (was "hilite"), the starting position of "unhappy" literally is 38. The new code returns 32. :(

Comment: Thank you for working through this with me. I've added some clarification to the OP.

Comment: Well, your question is very clear now. My solution is "B", which as you stated is acceptable, so what's wrong?

Comment: 1) Your code doesn't seem to work for the second 'people' in the phrase (real position 134 in your "highlight" version, but 121 from your functions which is 13 different not 15 or 18); and 2) to use the (B) approach, I now need to know what the clean (`&nbsp;`s removed or replaced with a space...doesn't matter) string is leading up to the selectedText and the end string (after selectedText). so that I can reassemble the string (begin string + selectedText (wrapped in new tags)+end of string).

Comment: You mean second "person"? (Not "people"?) Then that's because its position is 139 not 134. I [measured](https://onlinestringtools.com/find-string-length?input=a%20very%26nbsp%3B%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%22highlight%22%3Eunhappy%3C%2Fspan%3E%26nbsp%3B%26nbsp%3B%20person%20%3Cspan%3Emade%20life%20very%20difficult%3Csup%3Eproblem%3C%2Fsup%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%20for%20another%20&count-newlines=true) the length of the part before second "person".

Comment: To get the string before selected text you can call the `handleNbspsBefore` function from my code (rename it as you want). And to get the string after it you can call `cleanString.substring(getStartOf(selection) + selection.toString().length)`, which calculates the end position of selection (start position + length) and fetches the part of clean string on and after that position. `cleanString` can be obtained by replacing all `&nbsp;`s in dirty string.

Comment: Yes, the reference s/h/b to 'person' not 'people'. My error. And lets agree that the dirty string has a total length of 145 (measured [here](https://onlinestringtools.com/find-string-length?input=a%20very%26nbsp%3B%20%3Cspan%20class%3D%22highlight%22%3Eunhappy%3C%2Fspan%3E%26nbsp%3B%26nbsp%3B%20person%20%3Cspan%3Emade%20life%20very%20difficult%3Csup%3Eproblem%3C%2Fsup%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%20for%20another%20&count-newlines=true])) and that the first 'person' starts at 64 in the dirty string. Using the first 'person' is a better proof point because it has a string before and after.

Comment: Given the previous comment and that, your solution reports a start position of the first 'person' at 59 and that 'person' is 6 characters, the afterCleanString should start at 65 of the cleanString.  Correct? Now the only problem is that I can't get the afterCleanString starting position. First, to get cleanString we would use `const cleanString = dirtyString.replace("&nbsp;"," ");` right?  And then afterCleanString would be the tail of the string starting at 66. But the cleanString still has the `&nbsp;`s in it.  I must be doing something wrong...

Comment: Firstly, I'd like to notice that my code reports 49 not 59 on first "person". Secondly, why do you think `cleanString` will have `&nbsp;`s in it? You've already replaced them with spaces. Lastly, you'll also have to replace them in the selection, if you want an accurate end position of it.

Comment: Yes, the `cleanString` can be obtained like you've shown. And its part from position 56 (in case of selecting the first "person") to end will be `afterCleanString`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide an example.

Comment: In my testing, it seems that when you call `handleNbspsBefore()` with `cleanString`, an error results: `Uncaught TypeError: selection.getRangeAt is not a function` likely caused by sending a string to the function vs an object?  Also, I think we should use `replaceAll()` instead of `replace` to get the cleanString. Agree?

Comment: Yup, that's the cause. `handleNbspsBefore` accepts `Selection` not string.

Comment: What about `replaceAll` — my bad, forgot that `replace` only replaces the first `&nbsp;`. Updated my answer.

Comment: So does the reassembly code need to change (where you use `handleNbpspsBefore(cleanString)`)?  How to get the beginning string?

Comment: Whoops. Yes it does. Updated the code.

Comment: Don't forget to use your solution you commented to Heiko Theiben's answer.

Comment: can we have a brief conversation in chat?  Only problem is I don't know how to do that?

Comment: Do you still want a chat? Or is the question solved? I can create a room and provide a link.

Comment: Sorry I'm now a bit slow in responding.

Comment: @SNBS: The intro to this answer ("You didn't get my suggestion. I didn't mean...") may be a bit confusing for readers in the future. It presupposes there is additional conversation elsewhere that needs to be read to contextualise the material. Can you make an edit so that it reads more stand-alone?

Comment: Edited my answer. Hopefully it will one day be of use for you or someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The method [`surroundContents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents) comes in handy here: It helps locate the selected part of the editable div. Moreover, if it fails, the selection is something that could not be highlighted anyway, for example

```
Here is <i>some</i> &nbsp;text
      \_________selected____/
> s <i>some</i> &nbsp;tex (offset 6)

Here is <i>some</i> &nbsp;text
             \__selected____/
> fails
```

```js
function extract(div) {
  var contents = div.innerHTML;
  var r = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  r.surroundContents(document.createElement("_"));
  var start = div.innerHTML.indexOf("<_>");
  var end = div.innerHTML.indexOf("</_>") - 3;
  div.innerHTML = contents;
  console.log(div.innerHTML.substring(start, end),
    "(offset " + start + ")");
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable onmouseup="extract(this)">Here is <i>some</i> &nbsp;text</div>
```

Comment: Why — "couldn't be highlighted anyway"? If the user selects e.g. `text <i>text` and wants that to be bold, I suppose it should be transformed to `<b>text</b> <i><b>text</b>`

Comment: Actually, I do a pre-check of the user's selection to ensure that the selection doesn't overlap any other tags. So while it would be theoretically possible, it's not something we want or need to enable.

Comment: I spent some time getting the extract function to deliver the reassembled string. 1) I had to convert `div.innerHTML` to `div[0].innerHTML`; 2) to get to the actual selected string, I had to use: `let selectedText =  div[0].innerHTML.substring((start + 3), (end+3));`; and 3) I learned that javascript's replace() and replaceAll() have an issue with the literal `&nbsp;` as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19549559) made even more complicated by the fact that `contents` converts `&nbsp;` to `&amp;nbsp;`. Do you want to revise your post or shall I post the final solution?

Comment: Here's what I had to do to clean up extra spaces in the final string: first, create the beginning, selected (with new tags) and end strings like this: `div[0].innerHTML.substring(0,start).replace(/(&amp;nbsp;|&nbsp;)/g, '');` then assemble them together beginStr + selected + endStr.  If you create text strings first and then try to replace the `&nbsp;`s (in its various forms) in  the final, concatenated text string, the replace doesn't work.

Comment: Please post your solution.

Comment: @SNBS: Indeed what you want is how browsers behave when I press Ctrl+B (for bold) after selecting part of the contenteditable div. But the author has ruled this out for their use case.

Comment: In this application, the only tags being added are <span> and <sup> and they are being added by the application (vs. a user adding these tabs directly in the text). We're not editing text in the sense of making it pretty, but rather trying to identify snippets of text that have some value.

Comment: I've posted my rif on your solution.  Thank you for providing the essence of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this was a really fun little challenge! I don't know if I'm too late for the party but here's my code that works (famous last words:-)

In theory this code will find a correct position of selected text in any div not just contenteditable and will ignore any formatting as long as it's one level deep. So a main text container can have as many spans, subs as you want but each span can't have extra nested spans inside. It can be easily expanded just didn't have the time to add that, you can have some fun too!

**Explanation**

As the contenteditable creates various formatting by applying html tags it breaks your text in gazillion html element chunks.

When you call getSelection() it will return the selected text "element" in the DOM scope and that's where you can't really apply the instinctive logic that it's all in one div. You need to work kinda in the DOM scope.

So, the key points are:

1. Start by setting an empty "counter" var, that will count the length of any child elements that are not the selected target

Traverse all the children of your text container (contenteditable) div until you reach the **document.getSelection().anchorNode**

During that journey you may have to also traverse any sub-children of any container child.
Any child that is not your target selected node you will check for it's text length and add that length to the counter.

Now, the key here is to use the "innerText" when required, that effectively flattens that element and converts all the "&nbsp" crap to proper spaces.

2. If the selection spans across multiple contenteditable spans, subs etc. you will get that by checking the "getSelection().extentNode" property, that's basically where the last part of the selection end. Figure out what element that is and rinse and repeat the search for that element in the main container tree (again look for sub-children etc.)
3. finally, you should end up with the correct offset start/end based on your entire text container div **innerText**

I've done a rough example, it only works for one nesting level of sub-children but you can easily expand that with a recursive loop. This is more to show how this approach works.

```
//HTML
// we use the onmouseup on the text div to trigger the search for the selection, you can change that to whatever trigger you want

<div id="test" contenteditable="true" onmouseup="GetSelectedText()" style="border:thin solid #f00;">a very&nbsp; <span class="hilite">unhappy</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; person <span>made life very difficult<sup>problem</sup></span> for another person </div>

///
function GetSelectedText () {

   let text_container = document.getElementById("test")
   let all_text = text_container.innerText //<<< this flattens the text_container text and removes all formatting

   var selection = document.getSelection()
   let nodes = Array.from(text_container.childNodes)

    let target_node = selection.anchorNode
    let parent_node = selection.anchorNode.parentNode
    if(parent_node != text_container){ //this is not just a text element but something like span, sub...
        target_node = parent_node
    }

    let sel_start = 0
    let sel_end = 0

    let res = findNodeOffsets(nodes,target_node,selection.anchorOffset,selection.focusOffset)
    sel_start = res[0]
    sel_end = res[1]

    //bit of a crazyness here but basically we need to figure out if there is an extentNode what is it, a basic text node whose parent is the main text_container or something like span,sub...
    if(selection.extentNode.parentNode != target_node){
        let extent_target = selection.extentNode
        let extent_parent_node = selection.extentNode.parentNode
        if(extent_parent_node != text_container){ 
            extent_target = selection.extentNode.parentNode
        }

        let res = findNodeOffsets(nodes,extent_target, 0,selection.extentOffset)
        
        let final_end = res[1]
        sel_end = final_end
    }


    function findNodeOffsets(nodes,target, startOffest,endOffset){
        let chars_to_target = 0 //we will count the length of text in each node until we reach the node that contains the selection

        let start = 0
        let end = 0

        root_loop:
            for(node of nodes){
               
                if(node == target){ //we found it
                        start = chars_to_target + startOffest
                        end = start + (endOffset - startOffest)

                        break root_loop
    
                }else if(node.innerText != undefined){ //this is a parent dom element node i.e. span, sub...
                    //quickly traverse through this one to see if our target is here
                    let sub_children = Array.from(node.childNodes)
                    
                    for(let subchild of sub_children){
                       
                        if(subchild == target){ //we found it
                            start = chars_to_target + startOffest
                            end = start + (endOffset - startOffest)
                            
                            break root_loop
                        }else{
                            if(subchild.innerText){ //if this is an element like <span
                                chars_to_target += subchild.innerText.length
                            }else{
                              
                                chars_to_target += subchild.length
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
                }else{
                    if(node.innerText){ //if this is an element like <span
                        chars_to_target += node.innerText.length
                     }else{
                        chars_to_target += node.length
                     }
                }
            }

        return [start,end]
    }

    console.log("selection start: " + sel_start + " selection end: " + sel_end)

    // //test if it's correct using the all_text variable which is text_container.innerText()
    console.log("selected text: " + all_text.substring(sel_start,sel_end))
```

}

Comment: This doesn't work. When selecting the first "person" it shows start position 18, which is obviously incorrect. Tested [here](https://replit.com/@SNoteBookSystem/Test#index.html).

Comment: The asker needs the position to be counted **including HTML tags**, which have some length too.

Comment: And, unfortunately, the text can contain (as per the example in the OP) nested html tags, in particular like this: `<span><sup></sup></span>`

Comment: New solution handling any level of nesting posted as a separate answer as it's completely different and an edit of this one would be confusing

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete rework of the code I have posted earlier. Although it uses the same internal approach it is distinctly different so I thought to post it as a separate answer.

I hope that this code should do what the OP has asked for (if I understood the brief correctly). It's now using a full recursiveness to drill down through the tree of the text container and based on the selection retrieve the start/end offsets with all html markup included.

I've only tested it on a small sample and it produces correct results even with 2-3 levels of sub nesting. One thing I haven't had the time to look at handling is the `<br>` tags but shouldn't be to difficult to include. Also, the handling of various chars is currently this subset:`"&amp;","&lt;","&gt;","&sect;","&copy;","&quot;","&#39;","&#45;","&nbsp;"`

Intrigued to see if this works, it's been quite an interesting mental challenge :-)

```
//HTML - we use the onmouseup on the text div to trigger the search for the selection, you can change that to whatever trigger you want

<div id="test" contenteditable="true" onmouseup="GetSelectedText()"style="border:thin solid #f00;">a very&nbsp; <span class="hilite">unhappy</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; person person<span> made life very difficult<sup>problem</sup>smaller problem <sup> another problem <sup>hamster size plums problem</sup></sup></span> for another person <span>that<sup>has no</sup>plum problems</span></div>

////END HTML

function GetSelectedText () {

       let text_container = document.getElementById("test")
       let all_text = text_container.innerHTML 
       var selection = document.getSelection()

       let main_nodes = Array.from(text_container.childNodes)
       let startOffset = selection.anchorOffset
       let endOffset = selection.focusOffset

       let target_node = selection.anchorNode
       let node_path = []
       let break_loop = 0
       findNode(0,main_nodes,target_node,startOffset,node_path)
       let sel_start = 0
       let sel_end = 0
        for(let el of node_path){
            sel_start += (el.start + el.end)
        }

        let extent_path = []
        if(selection.extentNode != target_node){
            break_loop = 0
            findNode(0,main_nodes,selection.extentNode,endOffset,extent_path)

            for(let el of extent_path){
                sel_end += (el.start + el.end)
            }

        }else{
            let real_offset = countTagsToTargetIndex(target_node,startOffset,endOffset)
            sel_end = sel_start + (real_offset[1]- real_offset[0])
        }


        console.log("offset start: " + sel_start + " offset end: " + sel_end)

        console.log("selected text: " + all_text.substring(sel_start,sel_end))


       
        function findNode(i, nodes, target,offset,node_collection){
            if(break_loop == 1){
                return
            }
            if(i < nodes.length){
                
                if(nodes[i] != target){
                    
                    if(nodes[i].childNodes.length > 0){
                    
                        let sub_nodes = Array.from(nodes[i].childNodes)

                        let found = findNode(0,sub_nodes, target,offset,node_collection)
                        let tags = getOuterTags(nodes[i])
                        
                        node_collection.push({
                            node: nodes[i],
                            start: tags[0],
                            end: 0
                        })

                        if(found){
                            break_loop = 1
                            return 1
                        }else{
                            node_collection.push({
                                node: nodes[i],
                                start: 0,
                                end: tags[1]
                            })
                            
                        }
                    }else{
                        let real_offset = countTagsToTargetIndex(nodes[i],0,nodes[i].length)
                        node_collection.push({
                            node: nodes[i],
                            start: real_offset[0],
                            end: real_offset[1]
                        })
                        
                    }
                    
                    let found = findNode(i + 1, nodes, target,offset,node_collection)
                    if(found){
                        break_loop = 1
                        return 1
                    }

                }else{
                    let real_offset = countTagsToTargetIndex(nodes[i],0,offset)
                    node_collection.push({
                        node: nodes[i],
                        start: real_offset[0],
                        end: real_offset[1]
                    })
                    return 1
                    
                }

            }
        }

        function getOuterTags(node){
            let outer = node.outerHTML
            let inner = node.innerHTML
            let start_tag = outer.indexOf(inner)
            let end_tag = outer.length - start_tag - inner.length
            return [start_tag,end_tag]
        }

        function countTagsToTargetIndex(node,start,end){
            
            let encs = ["&amp;","&lt;","&gt;","&sect;","&copy;","&quot;","&#39;","&#45;","&nbsp;"]
            const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.appendChild(node.cloneNode())
            let html = newDiv.innerHTML
            

            let indexMap = {}
            let cnt = 0

            for(var i = 0; i <= html.length; i++){
                let flag = 0
                tags:
                for(let enc of encs){
                    const l = enc.length
                    if(html.substring(i,i + l) == enc){
                        indexMap[cnt] = l 
                        i = i + l - 1 
                        flag = 1
                        break tags
                    }

                }
                if(flag == 0){
                    indexMap[cnt] = 1 
                }
                cnt++
            }
            
            let realStart = 0
            for(let i = 0;i < start; i++ ){
                realStart += indexMap[i]
            }

            let realEnd = 0
            for(let i = 0;i < end; i++ ){
                realEnd += indexMap[i]
            }

            return [realStart,realEnd]

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Objective

When the user selects text within a [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) element, and right clicks the element, the selected text and it's containing HTML should be copied (or moved) so that it's [whitespace characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace) (ex. `&nbsp;`, tabs, line breaks) are preserved. The text is then modified by some process via AJAX and then returned back to the `contenteditable` element in it's original location. The text should have any original whitespace and/or text characters that wasn't changed during it's modification.

### Things to Keep in Mind

Each browser uses different HTML in `contenteditable` elements to obtain the same appearance (more or less since there are bugs (especially in Chrome)). In the live demo below, there are some measures to standardize browser defaults.

### Focus on [Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), not Index Positions in Strings

As far as the situation described in OP there are basically two [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)s to be concerned with: Element (`nodeType` 1) and Text (`nodeType` 3). In order to access the selected content, use [Selection Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection). In order to manipulate the nodes within the Selection Object , create a [Range Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range).

***Details are commented in example.***

```js
/**
 * Any comment with a dagger: † pertains to the <dialog>
 * which is used for demonstration purposes since there's
 * no way to prove how the selected text is preserved by
 * the using AJAX mentioned in OP.
 */
// Reference the contenteditable element to get the text from.
const A = document.getElementById("editorA");
// † Reference the element the text will be copied to.
const B = document.getElementById("editorB");
// † Reference the <dialog>
const modal = document.getElementById("modal");

/**
 * - Declare variables for Selection and Range Objects.
 * - † Declare a variable for the original copied text if 
 *   the user cancels any changes.
 * - Declaring (not defining) a variable with the keyword
 *   "let" ("var" as well but not recommended) outside of
 *   the functions allows it's value to be assigned and/or 
 *   reassigned later, be accessible to other functions, and 
 *   persist after a function's runtime.
 */
let select, range, original;

// Register the "contextmunu" event to #editorA
A.oncontextmenu = getText;
// † Register the "close" event to <dialog>
modal.onclose = setText;

// Event handler passes (e)vent Object by default
function getText(e) {
  // Stop the default context menu from opening
  e.preventDefault();
  // See below.
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox|fxios/i)) {
    lineBreak(this);
  }
  // Define Selection Object
  select = window.getSelection();
  // Define Range Object
  range = select.getRangeAt(0);
  // Declare variables for copied text and <span>
  let text, node;
  // † Open <dialog> as a modal.
  modal.showModal();
  /* Remove selected text from #editorA and keep it in a
  documentFragment Node. */
  text = range.extractContents();
  // Keep a copy of text.
  original = text.cloneNode(true);
  // Add text to #editorB.
  B.append(text);
}

function setText(e) {
  // † "this" is dialog#modal.
  // See below. 
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox|fxios/i)) {
    lineBreak(B);
  }
  // Create a <span>.
  const node = document.createElement("SPAN");
  // Assign <span> a class.
  node.className = "edit";
  // † If the user clicked a button with .value = "Cancel"...
  if (this.returnValue === "Cancel") {
    // † ...add the original text to span.edit...
    node.append(original);
  } else {
    // † ...otherwise get the content of #editorB.
    content = B.innerHTML;
    // † ...and add it to span.edit. 
    node.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", content);
  }
  /* Insert span.edit at the start of the Range Object 
  within the Selection Object of #editorA. */
  range.insertNode(node);
  // † Clear the contents of #editorB.
  B.replaceChildren();
  /* OPTIONAL - if you don't want a ton of 
  <span class="edit"> uncomment the next line - 
  See below */
  //unWrap(A.querySelector(".edit"));
}

/**
 * This function removes a given element but keeps
 * it's contents.
 */
function unWrap(selector) {
  let target = typeof selector === "string" ? document.querySelector(selector) : selector;
  const ancestor = target.parentElement;
  while (target.firstChild) {
    ancestor.insertBefore(target.firstChild, target);
  }
  target.remove();
}

/**
 * This function replaces <div>s with <br> which is
 * perferable over Firefox default of a <br> nested
 * within a <div>.
 */
function lineBreak(selector) {
  let target = typeof selector === "string" ? document.querySelector(selector) : selector;
  const divs = target.querySelectorAll("div");
  divs.forEach(div => {
    if (!div.querySelector("br")) {
      div.append(document.createElement("BR"));
    }
    unWrap(div);
  });
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 5vmin/1.15 "Segoe UI"
}

fieldset {
  border-radius: 4px;
  /** 
   * OPTIONAL - All whitespace characters are preserved and consecutive 
   * whitespace characters do not collapse.
   */
  /* white-space: pre-wrap; */
  box-shadow: inset 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.75rem rgba(255, 255, 255, .2), inset -0.2rem -0.25rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

dialog {
  width: 20rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}

input {
  float: right;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font: inherit;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px -4px #bbb;
}

input:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

input:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

#editorA {
  min-height: 3rem;
  margin: 10vh 0;
}

#editorB {
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0.75rem 0;
}

.edit {
  /* white-space: pre-wrap; */
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="editorA" contenteditable></fieldset>

<dialog id="modal">
  <form method="dialog">
    <fieldset id="editorB" contenteditable></fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Change">
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel">
  </form>
</dialog>
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest either:

1. Using ProseMirror OR...
2. Taking inspiration from ProseMirror's [documentation](https://prosemirror.net/docs/) and [open source](https://github.com/prosemirror).

ProseMirror is a (framework for building an) editor that uses `contenteditable` under the hood.

You might be able to just modify the [ProseMirror basic example](https://prosemirror.net/examples/basic/) to fit your needs. The [selection](https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#state.Selection) start and end are accessed via `let {from, to} = state.selection`. (Take a look at the [tooltips example](https://prosemirror.net/examples/tooltip/).) These examples support inserting HTML objects like images and `<HR>`'s.

I think ProseMirror has several advantages over a plain `contenteditable` `<div>`. But they are not without costs like added complexity and a steep learning curve. (For complex, niche use cases you may have to define your own document grammar.)

So another option is to simply emulate ProseMirror's method:

1. ProseMirror keeps track of the document content separately from the `contenteditable` `<div>`. This avoids the problem you are facing with `&nbsp;` being inserted for spaces. (Also I would be surprised if `contenteditable` behaves exactly the same on all platforms/browsers).
2. Then ProseMirror renders this document into HTML.

> ProseMirror provides a set of tools and concepts for building rich
> text editors, using a user interface inspired by
> what-you-see-is-what-you-get, but trying to avoid the pitfalls of that
> style of editing.
>
> The main principle of ProseMirror is that your code gets full control
> over the document and what happens to it. This document isn't a blob
> of HTML, but a custom data structure that only contains elements that
> you explicitly allow it to contain, in relations that you specified.
> All updates go through a single point, where you can inspect them and
> react to them.
>
> The core library is not an easy drop-in component—we are prioritizing
> modularity and customizability over simplicity, with the hope that, in
> the future, people will distribute drop-in editors based on
> ProseMirror. As such, this is more of a Lego set than a Matchbox car.

Comment: I will check it out.  It doesn't sound easy...

Comment: It is not reasonable to inject a whole framework into a project for solving just one issue.

Comment: @SNBS - I agree.  The use case here is an interview guide - a single page with lots of open text input areas.  There are > 20 contenteditable divs on the page and I can't see adding a full blown text editor into each text area.

Comment: @SNBS I also explained how to solve the issue without injecting any frameworks. ProseMirror already solved this problem, so you can examine its open source code and re-implement your own version. I gave a general explanation of how ProseMirror avoids this issue.

Comment: It's very very very hard to find the needed implementation in *such* a library.